# CMake "OBJECT" library: clang not linking properly

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, python-sip

I have a shared library (which currently compiles, loads and runs) `mylib.so`. From within this library, I want to use a new function (register it in another external library). The signature is `bool my_function(const QVariant *, PyObject **)`.

This new function is defined in a separate .cpp file which is compiled to an object and then linked to `mylib.so`.

So I create a new `OBJECT` with my custom function

```
ADD_LIBRARY(helper_lib OBJECT helper_lib.cpp)
```

And include this when building my library

```
ADD_LIBRARY(mylib SHARED source.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:helper_lib>)
```

It fails with an "undefined reference to `my_function'"

I can see that

- The `helper_lib.o` file is generated
- `nm helper_lib.o` shows

  `0000000000000000 T _Z11my_functionPK8QVariantPP7_object`
- `nm mylib.o` shows

  `U my_function`
- The `helper_lib.o` is passed to clang++ :

  `clang++ -fPIC [...] -o my_lib.so mylib.o helper_lib.o [...]`

I struggle to see where the mistake happens. I can imagine that there is something wrong in `mylib.o` which shows an unmangled symbol name which cannot be matched to the `helper_lib.o` symbol name, but I may as well be totally on the wrong track with this.

---

**helper_lib.h**

```
void my_function();
```

**helper_lib.cpp**

```
#include "helper_lib.h"

void my_function()
{
  return;
}
```

source.cpp is more complicated, as it contains mainly code automatically generated by [sip](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me with a simple source.cpp. So it must be that something gets messed up during inclusion, you can try moving `#include "helper_lib.h` to the top of your source.cpp.

To verify that this has nothing to do with your toolchain, you can try from a clean build directory the following project:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(dummy)
ADD_LIBRARY(helper_lib OBJECT helper_lib.cpp)
ADD_LIBRARY(mylib SHARED source.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:helper_lib>)
```

source.cpp:

```
#include "helper_lib.h"
void dummy() {
    my_function();
}
```

helper_lib.h:

```
#pragma once
void my_function();
```

helper_lib.cpp:

```
#include "helper_lib.h"
void my_function() {
}
```

Some [documentation](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library).

Comment: That did it! [Sip](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro) was putting the `#include` in some other part of the code and I had to include it in a `%ModuleHeaderCode` section to get it to the proper location. Thanks a lot.